# How to calculate the area of an SVG path c#

Tags: c#, svg

If anyone can help with calculating the area of an SVG path I would be very grateful.

I have a function to get the total length which works really well.

I've seen a javascript method that converts the path in to a polygon:

http://phrogz.net/SVG/convert_path_to_polygon.xhtml

Converting this to c# would be a good route as I have a function that gets the area of a polygon to a sufficient accuracy.

Regards

If there's any doubt as to what's being asked here......

If you know anything about the SVG file format, you'll know that SVG Path shapes are defined by a bunch of coordinates like this:

```
d="M195.303,64.357 c6.57-6.684,11.9-15.514,10.057-25.154 c-3.689-19.298-27.854-13.204-27.309-0.549 c-0.545-12.655-23.619-18.749-27.309,0.549                c-1.844,9.651,3.502,18.401,10.082,25.087 c1.697-4.813,5.713-8.03,11.482-9.451 c-2.797,1.531-3.809,4.396-3.809,7.812 c0,4.983,4.58,8.4,9.553,8.4s9.553-3.417,9.553-8.4c0-3.416-1.012-6.28-3.807-7.812C189.584,56.263,193.613,59.52,195.303,64.357 z"
```

c and C define bezier curves

(would have posted the image)

What I am asking is how to calculate the area for such a shape using the coordinates/curve points.

The solution using IronPython and the Inkscape function works really well.

Comment: If you've got a polygon routine already, then presumably all you need is an XML reader to grab the point data, and then feed the points into your function. Have you made a start on such a routine?

Comment: I can read all of the points no problem, the points for paths don't really translate directly in to the same format as polygons, paths can have various types of curves etc..

Comment: Ah, beg pardon - I just saw "polygons" and missed the "paths" bit! Right, as you were `:)`

Comment: I'm not sure if understanding the question correctly, but are you looking for the area under a curve, or simply the path length multiplied by the stroke width?

Comment: The example given is an incomplete implementation. It assumes that you are using flat polygons, specifically closed shapes that do define an area, rather than open shapes that define a path only.

Comment: Jlange, I need to calculate the area of a closed path, so it could be a combination of any curves, straight lines. It's the area of the 'fill'.

Comment: dwerner, the path shapes that i need the area for will always be closed. I'll have a better look through that thead. I have started going through the code in measure.py which does the calculations for that feature, but I don't know python at all.

Comment: what's not real about an SVG path shape area?

Comment: This is 100% a real question and 100% answerable. Should never have been closed. I can't answer it myself, but there's a free Adobe Illustrator plugin that calculates path areas (<=CS5). Illustrator's native format is not strictly SVG, but it is similar, so someone could read this (non-trivial...) code and get ideas for adapting similar logic for SVG and their language of choice. http://www.telegraphics.com.au/sw/product/patharea

Comment: Clipper by Angus Johnson does this thing in Csharp.http://www.angusj.com/delphi/clipper.ph

Comment: @NicholasKyriakides broken link?

Comment: @user1296173 Here Clipper in Csharp http://www.angusj.com/delphi/clipper.php    and  Clipper in JS: http://sourceforge.net/projects/jsclipper/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't work out the maths myself, so In the end I used IronPython to execute a python module from Inkscape which measures any kind of path accurately enough for what I'm using it for.

I'll post details If anyone is looking for the same, but it is actual pretty straightforward and doesn't require much editing of the Python files.
You do need to use .net framework v4.0.

Comment: I'd love to see details of how this is done.

Comment: Still waiting for the details, would be awesome to use same method as you did :)

Answer (score 10):

lets consider call the point of the closed poligon (x0,y0)...(xn,yn), you can calculate the area by simple looping through the point with that formula

```
area += yi+y(i+1) * (x(i+1)-xi)/2
```

Just to clarify with x(i+1) and y(i+1) I mean the **next** point in the sequence. The loop should start from 0 and stop at the n-1 vertex ( so the next point is always valid ) and when the last point is reached consider `ptn-pt0`
the area should be taken as abs, otherwise you can use the sign to check if the polygon is clockwise or counterclockwise.
I just add a drawing to explain how it works so you can extend to handle different types of curves. Lets consider this drawing:
[image]

The idea is to calculate the area of the green polygon by algebraic sum the area of each trapezoid individuated by a polygon edge and the x axis, in this case there trapezoid are:

```
x0,y0 x1,y1 x1,0 x0,0 
x1,y1 x2,y2 x2,0 x1,0
(-)x2,y2 x3,y3 x3,0 x2,0
(-)x3,y3 x4,y4 x4,0 x3,0 
(-)x4,y4 x0,y0 x0,0 x4,0
```

first two are positive, the last three are negative and as you can see the difference is the green portion, that is the needed area. I'm not so good in drawing, but try to figure out that the resulting coming out by the overlapping trapezoid that works in additive and subctractive way. Even if in the drawing I shown a convex polygon, the algo works for *concave polygons as well*.
In the case an edge **is not a segment** as a first solution what you have to do is convert it in a list of segment by using the parametric equation on the curve and sampling it, you will obtain a decent approxymation.
**A better solution** is to consider the *parametric function* of the non linear segment and  integrate it respect the X axis ( calculate the area between the curve and the X axis ) and sum it as I sum the area of the linear segments. This involves some math but you can find the [help you need here](http://www.mathwords.com/a/area_parametric.htm). You just need to use the correct segment equation.

Comment: Hi Felice, I've got a method very similar to that (which I got from this site I think..) fopr a polygon area, it's the Paths that I'm really concerned with. If I can convert a path to a polygon I'm hoping I can then use the same method.

Comment: @user1296173 a path is just a collection of points, exactly like a polygon.  What's the issue with using those points in the function?

Comment: @user1296173 you can use the collection of point as Slugart said. If some portion of the path are arcs... you can approximathe them with multiple segment, but there is a better way that I have to remember :)

Comment: hi Slugart, it's not exactly like a polygon, it can have curves and arcs specified  -- I have experimented with passing path points to the polygon area method, but the results are way out, usually negative values

Comment: Hi Felice, I'm not sure how to convert the curve control points to segments, I do not know about the parametric equation either, I haven't got any further with caculating the area of paths unfortunately.