# Use SVG or PNG for finding area of different part of the image

Tags: opencv, svg, image-processing, png, area

I need to calculate the area of the different part of the brain in about 600 pictures like this (List of different parts are in the bottom of the picture):

[image: Figure 54 of Paxinos Atlas]

[SVG of this figure.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1HM9KX01VPB4GkiFQWvRbpBQ6IX9MBOr_/view?usp=sharing)

I have access to both PNG and SVG of these atlases, which one should I use? If I want to use PNG files should I find contours with OpenCV? What about SVG files? High accuracy is not needed since I only want to sort different parts by area and I don't need the actual area so I'm looking for the easiest way.

Comment: Something [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9979360/how-to-calculate-the-area-of-an-svg-path-c-sharp)

Comment: It would be great if there was a general function which could return the area of a given SVG element (be it a path, circle, etc.).

Comment: Once you have <path> elements for every area, you can just go over every point {x, y}, find the path it belongs to with elementFromPoint and add the point to the path's counter

Comment: @MichaelRovinsky The problem is each area does not have a single path for example the outer top and left part of the brain where the parts are separated by dash lines, all of the dash lines are one single path.

Comment: Can you post your SVG here?

Comment: @MichaelRovinsky Sure, I added a link to SVG file in the question.

Comment: @SMMousaviSP OK I see it... I had an idea of replacing dashed lines with solid and then 'filling' the areas around labels one by one, but it seems to be overcomplicated... Good luck with it, anyway :)

Comment: @MichaelRovinsky Thanks, Actually I had the same idea about replacing the dash lines with solid it will make image processing easier after I change the SVGs to PNG, but I didn't understand why I should fill the areas around labels? By labels, you mean the name of each part?